# How can you execute php/sql code within a form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I want to make a form with a textarea that displays the tekst so you can modify it. 
If you press submit, it wil update the database table and return to the same page.
I thought you could insert code in the action attribute, but what about returning to the same page?

```
<form action=
            <?php
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
                mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());
                $strSQL = "UPDATE Ontstaan SET TeksOntstaan='" . $_POST["NieuweTekst"] . "'"; 
                mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
                header('Location: ModOntstaan.php');
            ?>
        >
            <div id="hoofd"> Pas de tekst over het ontstaan aan </div> <br>
            Tekst: <br> 
            <textarea name="NieuweTekst" method="post">
                <?php
                    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
                    mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());
                    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Ontstaan";
                    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
                    {echo $row['TekstOntstaan'];}
                ?>
            </textarea> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

File index.php:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['NieuweTekst'])){
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
        mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());
        $strSQL = "UPDATE Ontstaan SET TeksOntstaan='" . $_POST["NieuweTekst"] . "'";
        mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
        header('Location: ModOntstaan.php');
    }
?>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <div id="hoofd"> Pas de tekst over het ontstaan aan </div> <br>
    Tekst: <br> 
    <textarea name="NieuweTekst">
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
        mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Ontstaan";
        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            echo $row['TekstOntstaan'];
        }
    ?>
    </textarea> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can't write php code in the action parameter. There you only can say to which php-file the Request will be sended.

Were you searching for something like that?

Comment: Now I get this error :D Unknown column 'TeksOntstaan' in 'field list'

Comment: Means column 'TeksOntstaan' does not belongs to table "Ontstaan".